# Conjunction usage in sentence

Tags: word-usage, conjunctions

Which sentence makes the most sense?

> On 25 July, Russia joined Serbia in mobilisation **and in a** surprise to the Germans, as they thought that the Russians would take a long time to get ready for war.
>
> On 25 July, Russia joined Serbia in mobilisation **which was a** surprise to the Germans, as they thought that the Russians would take a long time to get ready for war.

Grammarly shows that both of these sentences are correct but I think it's the latter.

Comment: The second sentence, with _which was_, is probably the more common expression, but both the sentences sound fine to me. You might want a comma before _which_ in the second sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence has a faulty coordination:

> On 25 July,
>
> [Russia joined Serbia in mobilisation]
>
> and
>
> [in a surprise to the Germans, as they thought...]

The first coordinate is a main clause, but the second is an adjunct that lacks a main clause to modify:

> In a surprise to the Germans, as they thought that the Russians would
>   take a long time to get ready for war

This cannot stand alone as a sentence and hence cannot enter into a coordination with:

> Russia joined Serbia in mobilisation

The only other possible interpretation is that the Russians joined Serbia in both a mobilisation and a surprise to the Germans, but was Serbia's mobilisation also a surprise? It seems that Russia joining them was the surprise.

The second sentence is good as *Russia joined Serbia in mobilisation* is the antecedent for *which*, and *which*, in turn is subject of the relative clause modified by adjunct of reason *as...*